# Reading file from while loop not getting first line

Tags: bash

The following attempts to read from a file, gets the 2nd field of a CSV and performs actions if the field value is greater than the first argument specified for the command:

```
while  read -r line
do
       var="$(cut -f2 -d,)" 
       #echo "$var"
       if [ "$var" -gt "$1" ]; then
         # do stuff
       fi

done < someFile
```

I'm running into two issues:

1. The loop is not processing the first line. Am I missing something fundamental about how input redirection works? Or how it works with a while loop?

e.g. If `someFile` contains:

```
John,1,green
Bob,2,blue
```

the commented `echo` statement would only display `2`

2. The test `"$var" -gt "$1"` produces the error `integer expression expected`.

`$1` is always a numeric value. I've tried converting `$var` to an integer using `printf` but I've been reading there's no need to convert to an integer since `-gt` does implicit type conversion.

Thanks

Comment: `while IFS=, read -r _ var _; do` will prevent you from needing `cut` at all, and will put only the second column into `var`.

Answer (score 1):

`cut` is stealing your data.

```
$: cat in
x,1,x
x,2,x
x,3,x

$: while read line; do echo "[$line]"; cut -f 2 -d,  ; done < in
[x,1,x]
2
3
```

The `read` is reading the first line of my file into `$line`, which I echo in square brackets so you can see it. Then `cut` is processing the *rest* of the file, since both see it as stdin to the whole loop.

What you nead is to explicitly process the data you already read.

```
$: time while read line; do echo "[$line]"; val=$(cut -f 2 -d,<<<"$line"); echo "<$val>"; done < in
[x,1,x]
<1>
[x,2,x]
<2>
[x,3,x]
<3>

real    0m0.552s
user    0m0.106s
sys     0m0.401s
```

You can make it a lot faster/more efficient by skipping the `cut` subprocess and doing it with [built-in `bash` parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
$: time while read line; do echo "[$line]"; val="${line#*,}"; val="${val%%,*}"; echo "<$val>"; done < in
[x,1,x]
<1>
[x,2,x]
<2>
[x,3,x]
<3>

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

If you don't have an explicit reason to need the entire line with the separators still in it, then all you need is the `read`.

```
$: time while IFS=, read v1 v2 v3; do echo "v1=$v1 v2=$v2 v3=$v3"; done < in
v1=x v2=1 v3=x
v1=x v2=2 v3=x
v1=x v2=3 v3=x

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the variable `line` but you don't use it:

```
var="$(cut -f2 -d,)"
```

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
var="$(cut -f2 -d, $line)"
```

Or something like that?

Comment: By default it reads from stdin (From `man cut`: "With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input."). I omitted the file thinking that stdin would pass each line of the file as it proceeds through the loop.

Comment: I believe that's what's going wrong: your computer seems not to think that, but judging from your reaction, my proposal is a good try, but not more than that.

Comment: You mean `var=$(cut -f, -d2 <<<"$line"`)` -- though that's much slower than letting `read` separate out the second column.

Comment: @jjkl, "stdin" is where `read` is getting its data from, so when you let `cut` read from stdin, it consumes all the remaining data from `someFile` (and immediately writes it to its stdout, so it all goes into just one copy of `var`) so the next `read` has no more data left.